# how to determine if two file are identical in c using system call

Tags: c, linux, file, system-calls, stat

i need to see if 2 files are identical
so i used 
struct stat

```
    fdin = open(argv[0],O_RDONLY);
    statos= fstat(fdin, &stat);
    close(fdin);
    fdin = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
    statos1= fstat(fdin, &stat1);
    close(fdin);
    printf("file 1 is in size: %lu\n",stat1.st_ino);
    printf("file 2 is in size: %lu\n",stat.st_ino);
```

the result

```
file 1 is in size: 9569486
file 2 is in size: 9569479
```

why is the st.ino aren't identical for the same file with the same path??
and how can i do so if two different file are identical i could check it with system call

Comment: You're not opening the same file. How are you running it?

Comment: ./a.out ab.txt ab.txt

Comment: It's because argv[0] holds the name of the executable.  You should be using argv[1] and argv[2].  If you don't believe me, print the file names you're referencing.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the meaning of "identical". (Two "identical" files in the Unix sense are hard links pointing to the same underlying inode, which is stricter than having the same size.) What is your assignment requesting, exactly?

Comment: tanks..... 
should i use st_ino or st_size

Comment: Change the last two lines to `printf("%s is in size: %lu\n",argv[1],stat1.st_ino);printf("%s is in size: %lu\n",argv[0],stat.st_ino);

Comment: it said if the file are identical the progrem should exit(2) else exit(1)

Comment: are you trying to see if they're the same file, or if they're identical copies of the same file?

Comment: i just asked.... iddenticle in content--(identical copies of the same file)

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're opening two different files:

```
./a.out ab.txt ab.txt
```

`argv[0]` is the executable, `argv[1]` is 'ab.txt'.

If you put error checks into your code, it would be clear.

You're also printing the inodes as "size", for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

`st_ino` is the field for the file's inode number, The inode number is a unique identifier for each file's structure. The inode structure holds the information that the stat call returns about the file.

The field you want is `st_size`.

Comment: $ gcc main.C
$ ./a.out ab.txt ab.txt 
file 1 is in size: 4
file 2 is in size: 7393

Comment: for this  printf("file 1 is in size: %lu\n",stat1.st_size);
 printf("file 2 is in size: %lu\n",stat.st_size);

Answer (score 0):

You did not define **what *identical files* means to you**.

On Unix or Linux (or Posix), inside Posix compliant file systems (like [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) or [btrfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) but not [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vfat#FAT32)), a file can have none, one, or several file paths. So file paths refer to [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Then two file paths refer to the same underlying file if they point to the same inode (in the same file system).

You can use the [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) syscall to get the device (i.e. filesystem) `st_dev` and inode number `st_ino` of some file path. Then you should compare both of them.

Alternatively, you may imagine that *identical files* means to you files with same content. This is an ill-defined definition: a file's content may change (because it is simultaneously written -by [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), thru some [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ing, etc etc....- by some other process) while you are reading it. So *stricto sensu* **comparing file contents** (which is an expensive operation) **does not make sense** : the **content can be changed by some *other* process** during the compare.

If you wrongly ignore the fact that a file's content can change (because another process is writing into it at the same time you are reading it), you could read both files and compare each byte (also taking into account the end-of-file). Something as simple as :

```
 FILE *f1 = fopen(path1, "r");
 if (!f1) {  perror(path1); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  };
 FILE *f2 = fopen(path2, "r");
 if (!f2) {  perror(path2); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  };
 bool samefile = true;
 int c1, c2;
 while (samefile && ((c1 = getc(f1)) != EOF) || (c2 = getc(f2)) != EOF))
    if (c1 != c2) samefile = false;
 fclose (f1), fclose (f2);
```

<sup>You could optimize the above code by comparing first the sizes of `f1` and `f2` using [fseek(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftell.3.html) and `ftell(3)`</sup>

You could also use plain `open(2)` and `read(2)` and `close(2)` syscalls, be sure to read by chunks (of e.g. 4Kbytes) into a buffer (one for each file), and take care of the end-of-file condition, and to check for errors.

As others pointed out, your program is wrong notably because `argv[0]` is the program's command name.